# How to get Empathy contact list in GNOME shell extensions?

Tags: gnome-3, gjs, gnome-shell-extensions

I am trying to build a GNOME shell extension. How can I get Empathy contacts list in GNOME shell extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Empathy-IM tool is a reference-implementation of the "Freedesktop Telepathy"-specification. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telepathy_%28software%29):

> **How Telepathy works**
>
> Protocol implementations provide a D-Bus service called a connection
>   manager. Telepathy clients use these to create connections to
>   services. Once a connection is established, further communication
>   happens using objects called channels which are requested from the
>   connection. A channel might be used to send and receive text messages,
>   or represent the contact list, or to establish a VoIP call.
>
> **Applications**
>
> - Empathy
> - [...]

Therefor, you can use the [DBus interface](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/spec/#Contact-metadata-interfaces) to communicate with it. Gnome-Shell offers a Gjs/GnomeShell-Extension binding, which is explained nowhere, but example code is available:

- [Mailgroup post](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2013-February/msg00059.html)
- [Test-file from Gjs Source](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gjs/tree/installed-tests/js/testGDBus.js)
- [The "Media player indicator"-sources (uses DBus for communication, too)](https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer/blob/master/src/dbus.js)